# ORA-06512 when creating materialized view

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to create a mview in Oracle. It would be for a report I run everyday, so I would just need it updated before the execution, on demand.

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW mv_test
    REFRESH
        ON DEMAND
AS
    SELECT
        zzcode,
        COUNT(1) c
    FROM
        cdc.uap_zufi_t_dca_place@rbip
    GROUP BY
        zzcode;
        
BEGIN
    dbms_snapshot.refresh('mv_test', 'f');
END;
```

However, the below error appears:

ORA-06512: at line 2
23413. 00000 -  "table "%s"."%s" does not have a materialized view log"
*Cause:    The fast refresh can not be performed because the master table
does not contain a materialized view log.
*Action:   Use the CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG command to create a
materialized view log on the master table.

Comment: You need to set an alias for column `count(1)`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Still happening: ORA-06512: at line 2
23413. 00000 -  "table \"%s\".\"%s\" does not have a materialized view log"
*Cause:    The fast refresh can not be performed because the master table
           does not contain a materialized view log.

Comment: What part of the error message is confusing you? It's not only telling you what the problem is but also providing the action necessary to fix it

Comment: @NickW I've also tried CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON mv_test with rowid, but throwing error message.

Comment: Try `refresh on demand complete`

Comment: @astentx the same error throws :(

Comment: What does this query return `select refresh_mode, refresh_method from all_mviews where mview_name = 'MV_TEST'`?

Comment: @astentx demand complete

Comment: You need to CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON the table(s) referenced by the mv, not on the mv itself. In your case this would presumably be on cdc.uap_zufi_t_dca_place@rbip

Comment: @NickW It now says ORA-00949: illegal reference to remote database. Is it possible to creat this log in a db link? Is there any alternative?

Comment: I'm guessing you need to be logged into that source DB in order to create that log (or get someone who has the appropriate privileges to do it for you). I'm afraid I have no idea if you can create an MV in one DB when the source table is in another DB - but I'm guessing if you read the Oracle documentation it will probably tell you. It would probably be a good idea if you had a look through the documentation anyway

Comment: While not directly related to your problem, you should probably start using `COUNT(*)` instead of `COUNT(1)`. The expressions are generally identical performance-wise, with the exception that [some materialized view optimizations only work for `COUNT(*)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dwhsg/basic-materialized-views.html#GUID-932B8CD4-BF60-419A-9202-8A9FD5D24024).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really be using the `dbms_mview` package rather than the old `dbms_snapshot`.  They do the same thing in this case but Oracle doesn't even bother documenting the `dbms_snapshot` package any longer.

The second parameter of [`dbms_mview.refresh`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_mview.htm#i997194) is the `method`.  You're specifying a `method` of 'f' which means that you're asking for a fast (incremental) refresh.  If you want an incremental refresh, you'd need to create a materialized view log on the remote database (something you almost certainly cannot do over the database link).  Alternately, you can ask for a complete refresh instead at the cost of sending every row over the network every time

```
begin
  dbms_mview.refresh( 'MV_TEST', 'c' );
end;
```

Comment: Or leave the parameters blank to use default refresh method with no guess of how MV was designed